# background color depending on a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make the color of a div depend on the value of a variable :

```
var val=$('.sel').attr('number');
$('.sel').css('background-color','RGB(255,"'+val+'",0)');
```

But it doesn't work and I don't understand why ?

Comment: Have you tried to remove double quotes `'RGB(255,'+val+',0)'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need double quotes, get rid of them as rgb values dont have quotes around them

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var val=$('.sel').attr('number');
  
    $('.sel').css('background-color','rgb(255,'+val+',0)');
  
});
```

```css
.set{background-color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sel" number="25">aaa</div>
```